# Automating HTML5/ AngularJS based UI where id's are not added on elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ui-automation

I have an angular based app where I want to get automation testing done. But while developing we did not decide to add "id" attributes on the elements since they were of no use to us anyways.

But now while automating we realised that there are few tools available like onLoad Complete, QFT, etc which needs to uniquely identify the clickable elements while recording/playing back the test.

One approach to fix this is to go back and add id's to all clickable events but I want to know if there is a better way to fix this or a better tool available.

Comment: When using Angular you can use Protractor, which is specially made for Angular end-to-end testing: http://www.protractortest.org. There you're not stuck to id's, but can use several selectors. Protractor will use Selenium on the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can use selenium with the help of class,xpath,name attribute,tag name,partial name,by text etc. to find whether the elements exist and then execute some action on the element

Comment: yeah.. Selenium IDE is a better tool, though it behaves strange sometime.